# Meaning of stmt in gcc vectorizer debug output

Tags: c, gcc, vectorization

I'm trying to learn how GCC's vectorizer works, but I keep getting "relevant stmt not supported..." messages.

What does stmt stand for?

"statement"?

Update: Here's a code example, using strided access. From the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/tree-ssa/vectorization.html#vectorizab), it seems that this should work (see example11):

```
char *restrict from = (char *)fbuf;
char *restrict to = (char *)sbuf;
for (int i = 0; i < NPTS; i++) {
    to[i] = from[2*i];
}
```

I'm using gcc 4.4.7 on CentOS 6. My build command is:

```
gcc -o test main.c -m32 -std=c99 -Wall -O3 -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=6
```

Comment: That can probably mean anything. My guess is that the code doesn't match any vectorizable case. Could you post the code? It's usually easy to see directly from the code why it won't vectorize.

Comment: It's the same message for just about any loop that doesn't get vectorized. But I'll post a code example.

Comment: `stmt` simply means statement. The loop body is not vectorisable since `from[]` is accessed with a non-unit stride, unless your CPU supports gathered loads (i.e. implements the AVX2 instruction set). Example11 from the GCC documentation makes use of consecutive array elements in the two independent statements.

Comment: Not even AVX2 will help here. The gather loads on Haswell aren't "true" gather loads and they only support 32 and 64-bit granularity.

Comment: In any case, 4.4 is quite old...

Comment: @HristoIliev So if I understand you correctly, example11 in the docs only works, because, while the indices are strided, there are actually no input array elements being skipped in the loop. Is that right?